# rails grouped collection select for a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a form for a "Review" model and i am trying to generate a nested select tag with professors and the courses they teach.

The association between professors and courses is many-to-many through the join table "Offering".

The review belongs to an offering and I want to get the IDs of the offerings inside the nested select tag.

Here are my models:

```
class Professor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offerings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :courses, :through => :offerings
  has_many :reviews, :through => :offerings
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offerings, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :professors, :through => :offerings
end

class Offering < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :professor
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :offering
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And here is the Review form:

```
<%= form_with(model: review, local: true) do |form| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', locals: {resource: review} %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :body %>
  <%= form.text_area :body, id: :review_body, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :teaching_rating %>
  <%= form.range_field :teaching_rating, in: 1..5, id: :review_teaching_rating, class: 'form-control slider' %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :offering %>
  <%= form.grouped_collection_select :offering_id, Professor.order(:name), :courses, :name, :id, :name, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

What should I pass as `option_key_method` parameter to the `grouped_collection_select` method to obtain the keys of the offerings correctly?

If there is a better approach like using two separate drop down lists for professors and courses (with the courses lists updating when the professor is selected) or using a different `collection` or any other approach please suggest it. I am new to rails.

Comment: Having 2 separate drop downs is neat. You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1zZ4Lgzf9s).

Comment: Thanks @PavittarGill , will check it out. I will probably go with this approach.